# Use Folder of GeoTiff files as Store

Tags: geoserver, geotiff

I have a large number of GeoTiff files in a folder. I want to be able to access them using Geoserver. The two options I have seen till now dont meet my exact requirement.

ImageMosaic stitches all the images together. I need the ability to select which images to show. So probably a URL with the filename would server that specific file.

The other option of using an Image folder as a static file server does not render the images as tiles. My images are very large and I don't want to download the full image. I want to use the tiling capability of Geoserver.

What can I do so that I can server images in the folder as tiles, with the capability to decide which tiles to show.

Thanks.